# C# task "finishes" at Task.Delay? (WinRT)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, task, delay, async-await

I ran into this peculiar case with tasks and Task.Factory. So here's my piece of code.

```
public Task CreateAndStartSyncTask()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        ... do stuff ...
        await Task.Delay(500);
        ... do more stuff ...
    }
}

public void Synchronize()
{
    var syncTask = CreateAndStartSyncTask();
    syncTask.Wait(mTimeout);

    switch(syncTask.Status) {
        case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
            // VICTORY!
            break;
        default:
            throw syncTask.Exception;
    }
}
```

So here my problem is that when I run this glorious piece of code, I get to the switch case BEFORE "... do more stuff ...". The task then continues running until completion. This is not desired functionality as I would really prefer for the task to complete.

That being said, having it in it's own task here is slightly redundant in this specific context given the fact that it is treated in a synchronous manner but I can't fully disclose the code and I really need to understand the whole task completion mentality.

What's up and how can I actually check whether a task is REALLY concluded?

Comment: what is the value of `mTimeout`?

Comment: What do you get when you replace `await Task.Delay(500);` with `Task.Delay(500).Wait();`

Comment: mTimeout is around 10.000.

Comment: The Task.Delay(x).Wait(); seemed to fix the issue. I am still wondering what the logic behind Task.Delay setting the task's "IsCompleted" to true is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Use `Task.Run` instead. Both [Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) and [I](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) have blog posts that describe this in detail.

In summary, `StartNew` doesn't understand `async` methods. The `Task` it returns only represents the first synchronous portion of the method. To use `StartNew`, you either have to call `Unwrap` or do a double `await`. It's far better to use `Task.Run`, which does understand `async` methods.

Also, you don't want to block on `async` tasks (i.e., the `Wait` in `Synchronize`). Instead, you should `await` them. If you block on them, you can easily encounter a [deadlock situation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe on my blog.

Comment: That clarified it! Thanks!